# Prove $d(\vec{x} , \vec{z})\leq d(\vec{x},\vec{y})+d(\vec{y},\vec{z})$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

Prove $d(\vec{x} , \vec{z})\leq d(\vec{x},\vec{y})+d(\vec{y},\vec{z})$.

---

My attempt:

$$d(\vec {x}, \vec {z})= ||\vec{z}-\vec{x}||$$
$$=||\vec{z}-\vec{y}+\vec{y}-\vec{x}|| = ||(\vec{z}-\vec{y})+(\vec{y}-\vec{x})||$$

so we can re-write the problem as,

$$||(\vec{z}-\vec{y})+(\vec{y}-\vec{x})|| \leq ||\vec{y}-\vec{x}||+||\vec{z}-\vec{y}||$$

If $\vec{y}=\vec{x}$ then

$$||(\vec{z}-\vec{y})+(\vec{y}-\vec{y})|| \leq ||\vec{y}-\vec{y}||+||\vec{z}-\vec{y}||$$

Implies

$$||\vec{z}-\vec{y}||=||\vec{z}-\vec{y}||$$ 
$$d(\vec{y},\vec{z})= d(\vec{y},\vec{z})$$

This accounts for the equal part of the inequality  "$\leq$" I am not sure how to prove the "less than" part.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality). $$||\vec{x}+\vec{y}|| \le ||\vec{x}||+||\vec{y}||$$
It follows that $$||\vec{z}-\vec{y}+\vec{y}-\vec{x}|| = ||(\vec{z}-\vec{y})+(\vec{y}-\vec{x})|| \le ||\vec{y}-\vec{x}||+||\vec{z}-\vec{y}||$$